# ActiveMailer test pass when run through ruby but not when rake test:units

Tags: activerecord, encoding, tdd, testing, mime-types

I'm having trouble with an activemailer test I created.  When I run the test directly with ruby, the test passes.  When I run all the unit tests they fail, because the way the message is encoded changed.

Running the test from rake test:units breaks the email into multiple mimeparts, that do not exist when running ruby unit/mailer_test.rb.

Does anyone know why running rails tests one way would cause the message to be encoded differently from another way?  The code for my test looks like this:

```
@expected.from    = 'info@example.com'
@expected.to      = 'friend@example.com'
@expected.subject = "Regarding your inquiry"
@expected.body    = read_fixture('response_email')

@expected.date    = Time.now

assert_equal @expected.encoded.strip, Mailer.create_response_email("friend@example.com").encoded.strip
```

Thanks!

-Ken